# Show two unique exposed filters in different blocks for the same view

Tags: views, search

I have a view that has 3 exposed filters; two Taxonomy Terms and a Search Field.

I want the two taxonomy terms to appear in the Left Sidebar and I would like the Search Field to appear above the search results.

I have an additional requirement that keeps me from using the search API and the facets module so the only other alternative I can think of is to make this work using exposed filters in a block.

I have not been able to find a way to split these exposed filters. I have tried adding them both to separate blocks but all of the filters are showing in each block.

Is there any module or method that will allow me to provide this functionality?

Comment: Specifically, how do you want to split them?  If you just want to rearrange the way they are printed in the block, you can override the block with a twig template and print them however you want.

Comment: They will be split into two separate blocks completely. The two taxonomy filters will be in the left sidebar; however, the search field will be in a pre-content region that will be separate from them. Using the same twig template won't work, unfortunately.